# Why Admin don't see Profile edit option?

Tags: salesforce

I am new to the SalesForce. As an administrator I should be able to see edit page. Not sure why edit page not coming ?

Why I cant see edit, only clone. I am Administrator to this org.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that "Enhanced Profile User Interface" is disabled?  Go to Setup -> Customize -> User Interface page.  Under the "Setup" section, make sure the "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface" is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

setup>User Management Settings>
Under the "Setup" section, make sure the "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface" is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

There are few settings or things we can check for this issue:

- check admin permissions `Manage Profiles` and `Permission Sets`, best to check even on admin users.
- make sure profiles are not `Read only` or `Standard user`, as only custom profiles cloned from standard can be edited
- some license types are not editable (standard, system administrators, read only, solution manager, marketing user
- change your to a different view or list
- clean your cache / use a different browser / check your system logs / check with Salesforce Trust
- check organization-wide settings (Access Setup (gear icon in the upper right corner) => Quick Find (within the Setup menu) => Sharing Settings => Review the Organization-Wide Defaults (OWD) where you can find You can find settings for `Public Read Only` `Public Read/Write` `Private`)

These steps should provide a solid starting point for identifying the underlying issue.